# Error With My Hangman Game

Tags: python

I am studying Python through 'Invent With Python' for Python 2.7. Currently working on the Hangman chapter.

I went through the code 5 times in the last 3 days, but I am not getting the same result when running the code as I am supposed to.

My code:

```
import random

HANGMANPICS = ['''

    +------+
    |      |
    |      |
           |
           |
           |
           |
           |
           |
           |
           |
==============''', '''

    +      +
    |      |
    |      |
    O      |
           |
           |
           |
           |
           |
           |
           |
==============''', '''
    +------+
    |      |
    |      |
    |      |
    O      |
    |      |
    |      |
    |      |
           |
           |
==============''', '''


    +------+
    |      |
    |      |
    O      |
   /|      |
  / |      |
    |      |
           |
           |
           |
           |
==============''', '''


    +------+
    |      |
    |      |
    O      |
   /|\     |
  / | \    |
    |      |
           |
           |
           |
           |
==============''', '''


    +------+
    |      |
    |      |
    O      |
   /|\     |
  / | \    |
    |      |
   /       |
  /        |
           |
           |
==============''', '''

    +------+
    |      |
    |      |
    O      |
   /|\     |
  / | \    |
    |      |
   / \     |
  /   \    |
           |
           |
           |
==============''']

words = 'ant baboon badger bat bear beaver beetle bird camel cat clam cobra cougar coyote crab crane crow deer dog donkey duck eagle ferret fish fox frog goat goose hawk iguana jackal koala leech lemur lion lizard llama mite monkey moose moth mouse mule newt otter owl oyster panda parrot pigeon python quail rabbit ram rat raven rhino salmon seal shark sheep skunk sloth slug snail snake spider squid stork swan tick tiger toad trout turkey turtle wasp weasel whale wolf wombat worm zebra'.split()

# This function returns a random string from the list of strings.
def getRandomWord(wordList): 
  wordIndex = random.randint(0, len(wordList) - 1)
  return wordList[wordIndex]

def displayBoard(HANGMANPICS, missedLetters, correctLetters, secretWord):
    print HANGMANPICS[len(missedLetters)]
    print

    print 'Missed Letters:',
    for letter in missedLetters:
        print letter,
    print

    blanks = '_' * len(secretWord)

    for i in range(len(secretWord)):
      if secretWord[i] in correctLetters:
        blanks = blanks[:i] + secretWord[i] + blanks[i+1:]

    for letter in blanks:
        print letter,
    print

def getGuess(alreadyGuessed):
    while True:
        print 'Guess a letter.'
        guess = raw_input()
        guess = guess.lower()
        if len(guess) != 1:
            print 'Please enter a single letter.'
        elif guess in alreadyGuessed:
            print 'You have already guessed that letter. Choose again.'
        elif guess not in 'abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz':
            print 'Please enter a LETTER.'
        else:
            return guess

def playAgain():
    print 'Do you want to play again? (yes or no)'
    return raw_input().lower().startswith('y')


print 'HANGMAN'
missedLetters = ''
correctLetters = ''
secretWord = getRandomWord(words)
gameIsDone = False

while True:
    displayBoard(HANGMANPICS, missedLetters, correctLetters, secretWord)

    guess = getGuess(missedLetters + correctLetters)

    if guess in secretWord:
        correctLetters = correctLetters + guess

        foundAllLetters = True
        for i in range(len(secretWord)):
            if secretWord[i] not in correctLetters:
                foundAllLetters = False
                break
        if foundAllLetters:
            print 'Yes! The secret word is "' + secretWord + '"! You have won!'
            gameIsDone = True
        else:
            missedLetters = missedLetters + guess

            if len(missedLetters) == len(HANGMANPICS) - 1:
                displayBoard(HANGMANPICS, missedLetters, correctLetters, secretWord)
                print 'You have run out of guesses!\nAfter ' + str(len(missedLetters)) + ' missed guesses and ' + str(len(correctLetters)) + ' correct guesses, the word was "' + secretWord + '"'
                gameIsDone = True

    if gameIsDone:
        if playAgain():
            missedLetters = ''
            correctLetters = ''
            gameIsDone = False
            secretWord = getRandomWord(words)
        else:
            break
```

Can someone please tell me what the problem is -

1. As  I understand, I have messed up the indentation. Just can't figure where.

Please help.

Comment: This is too much for a single question. Extract a [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/), and describe one specific problem.

Comment: I am yet to know what SSCCE is. Thanks for the link!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Python is "space-sensitive". So this block of code

```
else:
    missedLetters = missedLetters + guess

    if len(missedLetters) == len(HANGMANPICS) - 1:
       displayBoard(HANGMANPICS, missedLetters, correctLetters, secretWord)
       print 'You have run out of guesses!\nAfter ' + str(len(missedLetters)) + ' missed guesses and ' + str(len(correctLetters)) + ' correct guesses, the word was "' + secretWord + '"'
       gameIsDone = True
```

relates to `if` clause just above it (`if foundAllLetters:`). Remove 4 spaces so `else` is on the same column as `if guess in secretWord`.

Comment: My friend referred to this website and said "Some awesome people hang around there. You'll get good help." Wow, I didn't know he literally meant it!. Thanks John. A solution in less than 30 minutes. Love SO already! I don't have much rep, or I would have voted your answer.

Comment: @SocialCoder You can't vote yet, but be sure to accept this answer when you can if it did solve your problem.